# Как составить рейтинг продаж продуктов ReactJS, JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs

Мне надо сделать рейтинг продаж (наиболее часто продаваемые изделия) в таблице.  Имеется массив заказов, в каждом заказе имеется массив из изделий. Надо пройтись по всем этим массивам, посчитать количество повторных изделий и добавить их в отдельный массив, который потом отрендерится на странице. Тут двойная вложенность, вообще не представляю как можно подступиться к решению такой задачи, может кто знает? На скринах модель и как это должно выглядеть в верстке.

```js
const orderList = [
  {
    id: '87ea9668-b6c6-4b7f-9e52-342fec4ec9e8',
    name: 'Order 1',
    products: [
      {
        id: '97d8dbb6-834f-4b67-a6e9-91577558aedd',
        name: 'Наполеон',
        cost: 5000,
        quantity: 1,
        quantityInOrder: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: '5a6b2e0a-f7fd-46a7-83ed-19b22db42c2e',
    name: 'Order 2',
    products: [
      {
        id: 'f4b9fce2-946a-43f4-a495-b32907189957',
        name: 'Медовик',
        cost: 2500,
        quantity: 1,
        quantityInOrder: 2,
      },
      {
        id: '97d8dbb6-834f-4b67-a6e9-91577558aedd',
        name: 'Наполеон',
        cost: 5000,
        quantity: 1,
        quantityInOrder: 1,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Исправил в соответствии с правилами.

Comment: Реакт нам говорит - декомпозируйте. Сделайте компонент который рисует первую вложенность, и компонент который будет рисовать например product и передавайте в него массив для рендера. Я бы еще и отрисувку единицы торта вынес в отдельный компонент

Comment: Спасибо, но проблем с рендером не возникает.  Мне нужно подсчитать количество повторяемых объектов по id в массивах products из каждого объекта в массиве orders.

Comment: Создай объект. Далее идешь по массиву циклом. В цикле еще один цикл, который в созданный объект добавит товар или увеличит его счетчик. Потом преобразовываешь объект в массив, сортируешь, фильтруешь(если надо) и получен массив с рейтингом продаж